# How to resize ec2 instance type dynamically using AWS Lambda function with Boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, boto3

How do I change Instance type for multiple instances with python lambda function without hardcoding the instance ids.

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

# Insert your Instance ID here
my_instance = <<some code here to fetch instance IDs of all instances 
filtering all t2.micro instance types>>

# Stop the instance
client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=[my_instance])

# Change the instance type
client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=my_instance, 
Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')

# Start the instance
client.start_instances(InstanceIds=[my_instance])
```

Answer (score 0):

Just supply a list, for example:

```
import boto3

client = boto3.client('ec2')

# Get t2.micro instances
response = client.describe_instances(
   Filters=[{'Name': 'instance-type','Values':['t2.micro']}]
)

instances = [i['InstanceId'] for i in r['Instances'] for r in response['Reservations']]

# Stop the instances
client.stop_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
waiter=client.get_waiter('instance_stopped')
waiter.wait(InstanceIds=instances)

# Change the instance type
for i in instances:
    client.modify_instance_attribute(InstanceId=i, Attribute='instanceType', Value='m3.xlarge')

# Start the instance
client.start_instances(InstanceIds=instances)
```

I didn't test the code, so please test it first!

Answer (score 0):

```
const boto3 = require('boto3');
const datetime = require('datetime');

exports.handler = async (event, context) => {
    const ec2 = new boto3.client('ec2');
    const instance_id = 'i-0123456789abcdefg'; // your instance id
    const current_time = datetime.datetime.now().time();
    if (current_time.hour === 12 && current_time.minute === 0) {
        await ec2.modify_instance_attribute({InstanceId: instance_id, Attribute: 'instanceType', Value: 't3.medium'}).promise();
    }
};
```

Comment: just need change id of your instance and create a cloudwatch to start them